# Is there any way to handle the flickering screen in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile 1.1.0 and I am facing a problem that when I run the application in the browser it works fine but when I run this through 'Home screen icon' it starts flickering the pages.

I am using iphone 5.1.

Does anybody have a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update to jQM 1.1.1, screen flickering issues have been fixed in this version. This problem affected running jQM in UIWebView container like PhoneGap, but I assume it's similar when you save it on the home screen.

Try updating and see if it'll fix your problem.

[Announcing jQuery Mobile 1.1.1](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/07/12/jqm-1-1-1/)

Comment: Actually, the flickering issues still exist in 1.1.1 and the 1.2 alpha version when using Safari on iOS, and launching in a UIWebView or a homescreen app.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the page transitions. If you disable them globally for the time being, you'll fix your problem. It sucks to lose the transitions, but the white "flash" is far worse.

Here's the docs on disabling page transitions: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html